# How to use extension on vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to using vs code. I added the extension called beautify. But when I save a javascript file, it doesn't beautify my work, it only stay the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1-Consider prettier much better
2-it contains text on how to setup it (if needed)

Comment: If u want beautify its shift+alt+F i think prettier is by saving (if no errors exist)

Comment: hi zein, where did you find that shortcut?

Comment: I came across it multiple times before

Answer (score 0):

@Nehan when I save the file it gives me bunch of errors and turns out lik e this -

```
function App() {
    return ( <
        div className >
        <
        Header / >
        <
        Note / >
        <
        Footer / >
        <
        /div>
    );
}
```

Comment: i really dont know whats going on i dont have my pc on me rn so I tried this code on https://prettier.io/playground and its working

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using prettier. After installation to setup format on save (formats your code every time you save the file) go to vscode settings and search format on save and tick the box.

[image: format on save]